# DESCryptoServiceProvider decryption not working. Getting output with \0 character and just first letter

Tags: c#, cryptography, memorystream, des, .net-4.5.2

I am creating a license from the following code with encryption as per the following logic:

```
private void SaveLicenseInfoWithEncryption(LicenseInfo obj)
                {

                    string strLicenseString = "Kamran";
                    //string strLicenseString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj, Formatting.None);
                    byte[] buffer = new byte[strLicenseString.Length * sizeof(char)];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(strLicenseString.ToCharArray(), 0, buffer, 0, buffer.Length);


                    DESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptSrvckey = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
                    {
                        Key = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptionKey"])
                    };
                    desCryptSrvckey.IV = desCryptSrvckey.Key;

                    using (MemoryStream stmCipherText = new MemoryStream())
                    {
                        using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(stmCipherText, desCryptSrvckey.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
                        {
                            cs.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                            cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                            string licPath = Path.Combine(txtFolderPath.Text, @"Test.lic");
                            File.WriteAllBytes(licPath, stmCipherText.ToArray());
                            MessageBox.Show(@"License File Generated Successfully");
                        }
                    }
                }
```

The license is generating fine (I have temporarily put sample text in). The problem is that I am trying to decrypt my license and I am getting some invalid behavior.

My code is:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog
            {
                Filter = @"License Files|*.lic",
                Title = @"Select a License File"
            };
        if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
        {

            byte[] buffer = File.ReadAllBytes(fileDialog.FileName);

            DESCryptoServiceProvider desCryptSrvckey = new DESCryptoServiceProvider
            {
                Key = new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EncryptionKey"])
            };
            desCryptSrvckey.IV = desCryptSrvckey.Key;

            using (MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
            {
                using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, desCryptSrvckey.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(ms))
                        {
                            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs))
                            {
                                sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());
                                sw.Flush();
                            }


                            ms.Position = 0;
                            txtContent.Text = new StreamReader(ms).ReadToEnd();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

In the watch window I am getting text `K\0a\0m\0r\0a\0n\0` but the final output in the textbox is just `K`.

Comment: Encoding issue. ReadToEnd() reads out the file contents as a string. Use on of the Read methods to read the bytes out to a byte array, then convert the array to a string using the appropriate encoding.

Comment: I also have that doubt.Have tried asciiencoding both in generation and decryption but that didn't work. Also I have tried StreamReader(ms, Encoding.UTF8).ReadToEnd() but it also didn't help. Can you please suggest which line of code required to be changed

Comment: This   **sw.Write(sr.ReadToEnd());**  needs to be replaced with a loop reading out the bytes to an array.  Then you can at least see what the data is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lose the `BlockCopy` and convert the string as UTF-8:

```
buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strLicenseString);
```

**Or** use your current code & tell the reader the text is UTF-16 (Which it is as thats the internal string encoding & is what ends up in your buffer when you do a raw block copy)

```
new StreamReader(cs, Encoding.Unicode)
```

You can also simplify to:

```
...

desCryptSrvckey.IV = desCryptSrvckey.Key;

using (MemoryStream encryptedStream = new MemoryStream(buffer))
using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(encryptedStream, desCryptSrvckey.CreateDecryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Read))
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(cs))
{
    txtContent.Text = sr.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strLicenseString); did the trick
Thanks a lot Alex